# What do you use for unit testing KendoReact components?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, jsdom, kendo-react-ui

I'm trying to encourage frontend unit testing and have been having a great time with testing-library/react.

We just got a KendoReact license for the Editor component. I'm trying to just render it in a "hello world" test and I'm getting `this.observer.takeRecords is not a function` from the prosemirror-view dependency.

`observer` in that context is a `new window.MutationObserver(...)`

My `testEnvironment` is "jsdom" and I have jsdom v20.0.3

I can see in the debugger that there is a `window.MutationObserver` in this environment, but the instantiated object only has the methods `disconnect` and `observe`

My component code right now is just:

```js
export default function RichTextEditor({defaultContent}) {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <Editor
      ref={ref}
      tools={[
        [Undo, Redo],
        [AlignLeft, AlignCenter, AlignRight, AlignJustify],
        FontName,
        FontSize,
        [Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough],
        [OrderedList, UnorderedList],
        ForeColor,
      ]}
      // contentStyle={{height: 120, width: '100%', margin: '0px', padding: '0px'}}
      defaultContent={defaultContent}
    />
  );
}
```

and my test is:

```js
describe('<RichTextEditor>', () => {
  it('renders default content', () => {
    render(<RichTextEditor defaultContent="Hello world" />);

    screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();
    expect(screen.getByText('Hello world')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

My initial Big Brain idea was to do `beforeEach(() => { window.MutationObserver = null })` because I saw the DOMObserver class won't try to instantiate it's `observer` if that's falsy, but it seems like that breaks something because the editor buttons get rendered, but no content.

I've also tried [@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim) which gives the same `takeRecords is not a function` error and [mutationobserver-shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mutationobserver-shim) was equally unhelpful.

Comment: I can see [in github](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/20.0.3/lib/jsdom/living/mutation-observer/MutationObserver-impl.js) that the jsdom 20.0.3 implementation of MutationObserver does have the takeRecords method, so idk what is going on

Comment: Ok SO, it turns out we did have a file in our repo that overwrites some global variables in the test context, and one of them was MutationObserver, and the overwritten class does not have the takeRecords method